# How to fill GraphQL ENUM from Django QuerySet?

Tags: python, django, graphene-python, graphene-django, graphql-python

In my `graphql` API for Revenue field use Currency `enum` from constant.

```
from graphene import Enum


CurrencyEnum = Enum('Currency', CURRENCY_CHOICES)

class RevenueMetrics:
    revenue = graphene.Float(description='Revenue', currency=CurrencyEnum(required=True))
```

But now `CURRENCY_CHOICES` constant has moved to DB (Currency table). There are good reasons for this (not related to graphql).

I can't figure out how to create CurrencyEnum class with dynamic filling from QuerySet of Currency table. Have an up-to-date set of Currencies.(I suppose that there is another question in the restructuring of the scheme).

```
graphene==2.1.8
graphene-django==2.13.0
```

I tried like this:

```
def dcm():
    return Enum('Currency', tuple((c, c) for c in Currency.objects.values_list('code', flat=True)))

revenue = graphene.Float(description='Revenue', currency=dcm()(required=True))
```

But it still requires a schema regeneration.